# Resuming/creating avaudiosession when app is in background(when it has been interrupted by call/alarm)

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I am recording voice in my app and currently it would run in  background .

1.Can I resume session after call gets ove.?
2. If resuming is not possible, can I create session again, record again ?

I have implemented both

```
 - (void)audioRecorderBeginInterruption:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder;


 - (void)audioRecorderEndInterruption:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder;
```

They both are getting called after and before interruption but I am unable to start new recording or resume recording after interruption ends.
DO anyone have any idea that How to implement that ?

Basically What I want is non-stop recording in background.The app should pause/stop recording when Interuption occurs and it should again starts recording when interruption ends. 
The app will continue to run in background.

One more thing, I don't want my user to click app and bring the app in foreground. The process should be visible to user.

Comment: Please help me . I am vetting irritated

Comment: Not sure to understand your goal... Are you trying to record in background? I don't think this is possible due to Apple's rules and the way your device works (that is device cuts background processes).

Comment: I can record in background. But the problem is that whenever we get a call on device, the recording doesn't resumes. There is session problem. So, my question is that, is it possible to resume avaudiosession while app is in background. Or can I start another audio session, if the app remain in background

Comment: @user3206985 did you get any answer for this? I am having the same issue. Please let me know how to resolve this.